# iOS String range(of:options:range:locale:) does work for valid regex

Tags: ios, swift, regex, string

I'm checking whether a string matches regex by:

```
string.range(of: self.regularExpression, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
```

for regex:

```
^[!-@[-~][ -@[-~]{0,254}[!-@[-~]$
```

I've validated the regex via a few online validation tools, but in iOS it doesn't work for the same string, for example: "company". Is there anything wrong, like character in the regex need to be escaped?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `[` inside the `[ ]`.

```
^[!-@\\[-~][ -@\\[-~]{0,254}[!-@\\[-~]$
```

You can also use:

```
^[!-~][ -~]{0,254}[!-~]$
```

if you run it on the `lowercased()` string.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the first one but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Your idea is correct, the `[` does need to be escaped, your first one got the wrong `[` though.

Comment: Odd, it works for me in a Swift playground. I did have a typo initially. Check it now.

Answer (score 0):

The whole string matching a regex can be done line this:

```
extension String {
 func isMatchingRegex(_ regexString:String) -> Bool {
        guard let aRange = self.range(of: regexString, options: .regularExpression) else {
            return false
        }
        switch self[aRange] {
        case self:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    } 
}
```